# Constraining when error recovery is allowed with Bison

Tags: bison

**tl;dr** Is it possible to only allow error recovery when the first token on a line is unexpected, but not otherwise? In other words, is it possible to prevent tokens from being automatically discarded upon error?

---

Suppose we have a line-based syntax where the following two types of lines are allowed:

```
start1 1
start2 1 2
```

`start1` must be followed by precisely one number, `start2` must be followed by two numbers. Any other word than `start1` or `start2` at the beginning of the line is disallowed.

In Bison, I handle this with the following (terminals are indicated by capitals):

```
line:
    START1 number NEWLINE
  | START2 number number NEWLINE
  | error alnums NEWLINE

alnums: ALNUM | ALNUM alnums

number: ALNUM { parse_number(); }
```

The following is invalid input, and Bison recovers from it by ignoring the entire line:

```
foobar 1
```

This is good.

But it also recovers from this (there is more than one number after `start1`):

```
start1 1 2 3
```

I do not want this. How can I disallow recovery for this case?

Error recovery should only be allowed when the first word on a line is invalid, but not otherwise. Is this possible?

---

Note: I know that it would have been enough to just write `error NEWLINE` instead of introducing `alnums`. But this is precisely the point. I'd like to allow recovery *only* when `alnums` matches. I'd still like to handle this situation as an *error*, so the parser can continue issuing reasonable error messages.

Comment: I don't understand why `error NEWLINE` doesn't suit your needs. Can you provide an example of what would happen if you use it?

Comment: @PiotrSiupa I want to recover from the error if the bad line is `foobar 1 2` (i.e. incorrect first word) but not when it is `start1 1 2 3` (i.e. an incorrect number of extra tokens after `start1`). The equivalent of `error NEWLINE` is precisely what I have in my actual code now, but I am hoping to be able to allow error recovery only for certain types of errors. Basically, in some cases the file should be parsed with warnings (for convenience), but when the error is "dangerous", parsing should be aborted (to protect the user). Maybe Bison is just not the right tool here (as you said before)?

Comment: One idea is to make a rule like `START1 number alnums` that isn't viewed by the parser as an error but it has `YYABORT` in its body.
However, I'm thinking that you're trying to put too much on the parser. Parser is concerned with syntax. It either understands (syntactically) what user wrote or it's a gibberish. Situations like "I understand what user wrote but this is not legal" are more fitting to be handled by some separate algorithm that's concerned with semantic.